# store objects in associative array

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

How do I store ExtendScript objects in associative array?

```
var assArray = {};

for (i=1; i<=app.project.items.length; i++) {
    //alert(app.project.item(i).name); one of them is "_vegs"
    assArray[app.project.item(i).name] = app.project.item(i);
}

alert(assArray["_vegs"].name);
```

This code returns error at the second alert line.

```
Unable to execute script at line 9. undefined is not an object.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you count from 1 to `length`, why not from 0 to `length-1` ?

Comment: this is ExtendScript. Adobe starts with 1.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What error does it return? Do you mean `items` or `item`?

Comment: Replaced it with assArray so that there is less confusion.

Comment: Checkout "push". var myarray = [] and then myarray.push(...), see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push and sorry for micro editing :-)

Comment: I'd use a different name ...

Comment: assArray is fine :D

Comment: @Gunnar I need to access items by its name later on. I don't want to use normal array.

Comment: @sanjihan, I created a dummy project with item named `_vegs` and ran your code and it works fine. Probably you have different error. Try running your code on dummy project.

Comment: @sanjihan I can not confirm your error. It works for me as well. Didn't have `_vegs` in it but other names with whitespaces. The error must come from something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
var assArray = {};

for (i=1; i<=app.project.items.length; i++) {
    //alert(app.project.item(i).name); one of them is "_vegs"
    assArray[app.project.item[i].name] = app.project.item[i];
}

alert(assArray["_vegs"].name);
```

I think the problem is in (i) hopefully [i] will work

Comment: Nah, item() is a function in extendscript. It looks like they don't allow storing objects in arrays.